# ¿Como pasar los datos de una columna de un datagridview a otra columna usando AllowUserToOrderColumn en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ordenamiento, datagridview

Buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente, quiero que el usuario importe datos de distintas fuentes (.txt, .csv, .xls, etc) pero quiero que el usuario pueda reacomodar los datos en la columna correspondiente con solo arrastrarla para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0" class="tg"><thead><tr><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</th><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</th><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</th><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1.1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3.1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2.1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4.1</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1.2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3.2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2.2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4.2</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1.3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3.3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2.3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4.3</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0" class="tg"><thead><tr><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1</th><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2</th><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3</th><th style="background-color:#9b9b9b;border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1.1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2.1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3.1</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4.1</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1.2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2.2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3.2</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4.2</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">1.3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">2.3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">3.3</td><td style="border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">4.3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

dejando unicamente el AllowUserToOrderColumns = True puedo reacomodar las columnas pero el indice no cambia, solo cambia el ViewIndex, pero yo necesito leer los datos de izquierda a derecha tal cual se muestra en la segunda tabla. Se que el index de las columnas es ReadOnly y no se puede cambiar asi que estoy buscando como pasar los datos de una columna a otra cuando el usuario arrastre la columna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes conocer la nueva posición en que se encuentra cada columna a través de las propiedades .Column(i).Index (da la posición original) y .Column(i).DisplayIndex (da la posición en la vista). Así, que para recorrer las columnas, por ejemplo en el orden original sólo hay que valerse de .Column(i).Index:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged
    Try
        Dim str As String = "Para leer en el orden original: " + vbCrLf
        With DataGridView1
            For j = 0 To .Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed) - 1
                str += String.Format("Nueva posición de la columna num({0}) {1} = {2}",
             .Columns(j).Index, .Columns(j).Name, .Columns(j).DisplayIndex) + vbCrLf
            Next
        End With
        MsgBox(str)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```